# Angular checklist-model checkboxes with reverse action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, reverse

I'm working with [checklist-model.js](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) for angular to select from dynamically generated list of objects. It's working fine, but now I need to make it work in reverse so when I uncheck any of checkbox - place it to new array (and when checked back - remove from array). Can any of You give me some ideas or tell me next steps how to deal with it?

html:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"
        ng-model="check_all_domains"
        ng-click="toggle_select_all()"/> all
</label>
<label ng-repeat="objects in objects_model">
    <input type="checkbox"
        checklist-model="objects_selected"
        checklist-value="objects"
        ng-checked="check_all_domains"/>
    {{objects.name}}
</label>
```

model:

```
$scope.objects_model = [
    {id : '1', name: 'name1'},
    {id : '2', name: 'name2'},
    {id : '3', name: 'name3'},
  ];
$scope.objects_selected = [];
$scope.check_all_domains = false;

$scope.toggle_select_all = function() {
    $scope.objects_selected = [];
};
```

here is screenshot how it's **working right now**:

[image]

and here is **how I want it to work:**

[image]

UPDATED: WORKING AS IT SHOULD [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rLjdtmpizblVnlxKwHPi?p=preview)

Comment: Don't think the plugin is intended to be used like that plus that you cannot have "all" checked and the one not checked as it doesn't make sense. Also in the selected object you are showing the objects not selected which is not what the plugin does. You will need to create your own directive/s in order to achieve what you want

Comment: @Lau if i send empty array to server, it knows that everything was selected, but imagine if there are 10000 objects and I want to exclude only few of them, then i'm sending to server those excluded with "all_selected:true" option and server knows what to do. Ok, I'll think about extending this plugin by myself

Comment: It goes the same way around because if you want to select only one from the 10000 object the you will send to the server 9999 objects :)

Comment: @Lau no, I'll only send `{check_all_domains: false}` and 1 selected object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rLjdtmpizblVnlxKwHPi?p=preview)** in question so have a look at the final result

```
<label ng-repeat="objects in objects_model" class="test">
    <input type="checkbox" 
          checklist-model="objects_selected" 
          checklist-value="objects" />
    <i ng-class="{checked : check_all_domains, 
                unchecked : !check_all_domains, 
                fakecheck : check_all_domains}"></i>{{objects.name}}
  </label>
```

Comment: this demo is not working, you are styling like checked but your model doesn't has the objects you checked

Comment: @Octavioamu the demo is working perfectly - if everything is checked (separate checkbox), then only `{all_domains_checked: true}` is sent to the backend

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with checklist-model and I've managed to create a workaround

Although its a pretty nasty solution, it works:

```
$scope.toggle_select_all = function() {
   $timeout(function() {
       $scope.check_all_domains = $scope.check_all_domains ? false : true;
   });

   if (!$scope.check_all_domains) {
      angular.copy($scope.objects_model, $scope.objects_selected);
   } else {
      angular.copy([], $scope.objects_selected);
   }
};
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CiXO1debaDkKPHPYKNfT?p=preview

---

I'd highly suggest searching for an alternative, cause later on you'll see that it pays off.

For me this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/cjwprostar/M4vGj/6/  - Chris Waguespack

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/KMS5hXn1OCI