# Checklist-model in Angular usage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, checklist-model

i have departments as a title and employees as a subtitle. what i want to do is when the user check the title or department all employees or subtitles should be checked.  i am using fieldset and table in html and ng-repeat. it looks like this issue but the main differ is getting data from db [Angular checklist-model checkboxes with reverse action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866463/angular-checklist-model-checkboxes-with-reverse-action)
i cannot find what i miss. any idea any help. thanks .

The HTML

```
<fieldset id="field3">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="emp in empdepts | groupBy:'dep_LDesc'">
                    <td>
                        <label ng-click="showContent = !showContent"></label>
                        <details ng-open="showContent">
                            <summary> <input type="checkbox" class="test" ng-model="check_all_domains" ng-click="toggle_select_all()" /> {{emp[0].dep_LDesc}}</summary>

                            <div ng-repeat="semployee in emp" class="test">

                                <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="objects_selected" checklist-value="semployee">

                                {{semployee.Sname}}<div style="display:none;">{{semployee.staffkey}}{{semployee.depkey}}</div>

                              </div>
                        </details>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
```

The Controller

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/angular.js" />
```

/// 
///

```
Assign.controller("AssignController", function ($scope, Assignments) {

Loaddepts();
function Loaddepts()
{
    Assignments.getdepts().then (function(response){

        $scope.depts = (response.data);
        console.log($scope.depts);
    })

}

//$scope.employees = [];
//$scope.checked = { employees: ['semployee'] }
//$scope.checkAll = function () {
//    $scope.checked.employees = angular.copy($scope.employees);
//};
//$scope.uncheckAll = function () {
//    $scope.checked.employees = [];
//};


//$scope.emp = $scope.empdepts;
$scope.objects_selected = [];
$scope.check_all_domains = false;
$scope.toggle_select_all = function () {
    $scope.objects_selected = true;
    //$scope.check_all_domains = true;
    //$scope.objects_selected = angular.copy($scope.emp);
   //angular.copy($scope.emp, $scope.objects_selected);
};




LoadEmpDepts();
function LoadEmpDepts()
{
    Assignments.getempdepts().then (function (response){

        $scope.empdepts = (response.data);
        console.log($scope.empdepts);
     })
}


$scope.selectedRow1 = null;  // initialize our variable to null
$scope.setClickedRow1 = function (employee) {  //function that sets the value of selectedRow to current index
    $scope.selectedRow1 = employee;
}






$scope.save = function()
{

}
```

});

[image]

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: any help or idea to solve this issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
                <tr ng-repeat="e in empdepts | groupBy:'dep_LDesc'">
                    <td>
                        <label ng-click="showContent = !showContent"></label>
                        <details ng-open="showContent">
                            <summary><input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk"  /> {{e[0].dep_LDesc}}</summary> 

                            <div ng-repeat="employee in e">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="chk"> {{employee.Sname}} 
                            </div>
                        </details>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```